# How to conduct survival analysis based on genotypes with R package "survival"

Tags: r

Recently I wanna conduct a survival analysis to examine the association between genotypes and survival time. I've been searching for help documents online but nothing have been found yet. I hope someone could give me a hand and help me out. Really appreciated it!

I already know how to conduct the survival analysis based on gene expression levels(as in the following code), but I have trouble tweaking this code to make it right for my genotype-based survival analysis.

```r
require(data.table)
genotypes_OS<- fread("genotypes_clinical.txt",header = TRUE)
genotypes_matirx <- as.matrix(genotypes_OS)
OS.time <- as.numeric(genotypes_matirx [,2])
OS.status <- (genotypes_matirx [,3])
genotypes_OS_TPM <- genotypes_OS[,c(1,4:13)]

n <- genotypes_OS_TPM$sampleID
genotypes_OS_TPM <- as.data.frame(t(genotypes_OS_TPM[,-1]))
colnames(genotypes_OS_TPM) <- n

library(survival)
my.surv <- Surv( OS.time,OS.status=="DECEASED")
fit.KM=survfit(my.surv~1)
fit.KM

cox_results <- apply(genotypes_OS_TPM , 1, function(values1){
  group=ifelse(values1>median(values1),'high','low')
  survival_OS <- data.frame(group=group,stringsAsFactors = F)
  m=coxph(my.surv ~ group, data =  survival_OS)
  beta <- coef(m)
  se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(m)))
  HR <- exp(beta)
  HRse <- HR * se
  tmp <- round(cbind(coef = beta, se = se, z = beta/se, p = 1 - pchisq((beta/se)^2, 1),
                     HR = HR, HRse = HRse,
                     HRz = (HR - 1) / HRse, HRp = 1 - pchisq(((HR - 1)/HRse)^2, 1),
                     HRCILL = exp(beta - qnorm(.975, 0, 1) * se),
                     HRCIUL = exp(beta + qnorm(.975, 0, 1) * se)), 3)
  return(tmp['grouplow',])
})
DT::datatable(cox_results ,
              extensions = 'FixedColumns',
              options = list(
                #dom = 't',
                scrollX = TRUE,
                fixedColumns = TRUE
              ))

cox_results_T <- t(cox_results)
write.table(cox_results_T,"cox_result.txt", sep ="\t", quote=F)
```

In case of need, I'll put a piece of sample data "genotypes_clinical.txt" here

```
sampleID    Overall_Survival    Status  rs2095567   rs7917494   rs7900790   rs7917750   rs7901150   rs7918021   rs7901545   rs7901547   rs11592132  rs11596383
3B-AAB1 2.17    DECEASED    2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   2   2
3B-AAB4 23.95   LIVING  2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   2   2
3B-AAB6 9.63    DECEASED    2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   2   2
3B-AABI 31.83   LIVING  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3B-AABK 15.9    LIVING  2   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
3B-AABT 10.48   LIVING  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3B-AABU 9.1 DECEASED                                0   1   
3B-AABV 21.42   DECEASED    2   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
2L-AAQA 4.7 DECEASED    2   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
2L-AAQL 9.59    DECEASED    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2L-AAQM 45.43   LIVING  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
5D-A9I5 58.94   LIVING  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
5D-A9I7 43.46   LIVING  2   1   1   1   1   1       1   1   1
5D-A9I9 20.83   DECEASED    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5D-A9IB 7.36    DECEASED    2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   2   2
5D-A9IC 24.24   DECEASED    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5D-A9IH 33.54   LIVING  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
Q3-A5QY 13.67   LIVING  2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   2   2
Q3-AA2A 3.12    LIVING  2   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
RB-A7B8 15.31   DECEASED    1                       1           
RB-AA9M 9.4 LIVING  2   2   2   2   2   2   0   2   2   2
RL-AAAS 0.3 LIVING  2   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
S4-A8RM 24.21   LIVING  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
S4-A8RO 17.25   LIVING  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
S4-A8RP 23.06   DECEASED    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: What is the output when you run your code with the full dataset? Is there an error? Also, it appears you're grouping on high vs low for genotypes the same way you did for gene expression. Is that right? Seems like what you want to do is calculate hazard ratios using genotype as a continuous variable (0/1/or 2 variant alleles).

Comment: The code I provided up there was the code for gene expression, I just havent figured out how could I tweak my code to make it work for genotypes. And I didnt intended to use genotypes as continuous variables, 0, 1, 2 here stand for three classifications: wide type, heterozygous mutation，homozygous mutation@TJ87

Comment: If you make those "genotype" columns into factors you should be able to get any ordinary R regression function to give you meaningful output, but I don't see how using `apply` is likely to be useful on a row-wise basis. You need to give the second argument to `Surv` as the exact spelling of a column name WITHOUT quotes inside the formula argument to `survfit` using a data argument. You should not be creating `Surv` objects outside the regression call. AND you've got a lot of rows with missing data. No help possible. Voting to close.